# How can I discover whether a particular piece of data is encrypted?

Tags: java, android

How can I discover whether a particular piece of data (say, a string, or file data) is encrypted? I wish to discover this programmatically, rather than via manually inspection.

Comment: Even unencrypted-looking data can be encrypted, embedded, etc. And funds need to distinguish *that* from data-in-known-but-not-plaintext-format. There's zero way to do this and guarantee correctness.

Comment: All you want to do is know whether data is encrypted? What possible benefit do you get from that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no formal procedures to find out is data encrypted or not. Even manually it is not always possible to understand what kind of data we are dealing with.

Trying to decrypt a piece of data with all available decryption algorithms will take significant time and does not guarantee 100% result which can be trusted.

For your applications send a flag to the recipent to make a signal that data is encrypted/is not encrypted.

Comment: I am completely blank about the data which is coming to my application & i cant control the data which is coming from another application

Comment: As I mentioned before there's no formal way to determine  data nature.